# How to create "Certificate Signing Request" run on all version of window using Xenroll and CertEnroll?

Tags: c++, winapi, cryptography, cryptoapi, csr

I have project must create Certificate Signing Request (CSR), then i use Xenroll api. But the problem is when i use Xenroll.dll (supported in Window XP) but when in window vista and new version of window, this DLL reconstructed and rename to CertEnroll.dll (Xenroll now no exit in newer version, and in lower version don't have CertEnroll.dll).

How to create "Certificate Signing Request" run on all version of window using Xenroll and CertEnroll ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no OS-version agnostic API for this purpose in Windows. My solution was to use Xenroll.dll on XP & Win Server 2003, and CertEnroll.dll on Vista and above, by checking the Major part of the OS version before generating the CSR.